# Object Detection Using WebRTC and Kurento

Tags: object-detection, kurento

I have been following a very interesting tutorial about "Kurento" the media server for the WebRTC which allows multimedia communication directly through browsers. I have run the tutorials here http://www.kurento.org/docs/current/tutorials.html and have found it interesting.

My plan now is to implement a very basic object detection/recognition algorithm based on WebRTC (or Kurento) that given a simple object, it can detect it. In order to do this, I thought about the following steps.

Let's say we wish to find fruits, like apples and oranges:

- Step 1 : I want to put a fix bounding box on the screen that limits the detection area, like the US-green card photo tool: http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/photos.html

(The green shape around the user face)

- Step 2 : Implement a button that once pressed it can tell you the object inside the bounding box is apple or orange (e.g. based on its color or shape)

If there are ideas, I appreciate if I could know about them. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create your own module for that. There is a piece of [documentation](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mastering/develop_kurento_modules.html) regarding that. You can use any of the existing modules as example, but I think the [face detector filter](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-filters/tree/f7153be2fa7ec350a890b4ec66cefd1fc23364a2/src/gst-plugins/facedetector) is quite similar to what you are proposing.

Creating pluggable modules for Kurento is very easy. The hardest part is adding the computer vision algorithms inside those modules ;-)

Comment: Thanks, another question I had about this is that in Kurento documentation, three types of programming frameworks are provided: (1) JAVE EE (2) Java script (3) node.js.

What consideration should be taken intro account in order to choose any of the above flavors?

Comment: Just choose the one you are more familiar with. Take into account that pure JavaScript clients are for architectures where there is no signaling server between KMS and your clients. Have a look at [this](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introducing_kurento.html#kurento-api-clients-and-protocol) document for more info about the different possible architectures.
Note: (1) is a pure Java client, not Java EE.

Comment: No worries! Please accept the answer if its valid for you. Otherwise, I can expand.

Comment: I am going to , thanks for the remind. May you kindly recommend the best source I can take in order to be able to use OpenCV in integration with Kurento? I am a robust MATLAB programmer but have little knowledge on OpenCV. I plan to implement a solution like this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uz4lv-V2qyc . Thanks Igracia

Comment: Check any of the already implemented filters, like for instance the [chroma](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-chroma) filter.